# Spring security @PreAuthorize not working

Tags: spring, security, methods

I have working basic security example, now I need to add @PreAuthorize on API level. in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public Data userHome() {
    Data d = new Data();
    d.setName("user");
    d.setRollNo(5);
    d.setD(new Date());
    return d;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public Data adminHome() {
    Data d = new Data();
    d.setName("admin");
    d.setRollNo(2);
    return d;
}
```

spring security configuration is as below

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
        <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
            <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
            <remember-me />
            <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        </http>
        <debug />
        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service id="userService">
                    <user name="admin" password="{noop}admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="user" password="{noop}user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
        <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
   class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder"
            factory-method="getInstance" />
        <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />
    </beans:beans>
```

authentication is working fine, the issue is that even user with ROLE_USER is able to access /admin API, so does user with ROLE_ADMIN can access /user API, I have used `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` but it dosent seems to be working, what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Authority** and **Role** causes confusion.

You should use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")` or `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")`.

`hasAuthority(‘ROLE_USER’)` is similar to `hasRole(‘USER’)` because the **‘ROLE_‘ prefix** gets added automatically.